# Is the group of translations of an affine plane always commutative?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, incidence-geometry, transformation-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Dil{Dil}\DeclareMathOperator\Trans{Trans}\DeclareMathOperator\Col{Col}$An *affine plane* is a set of *points* $X$ endowed with a family $\mathcal L$ of subsets of $X$, called *lines*, such that the following axioms hold:

1. for every distinct points $x,y\in X$ there exists a unique line $L\in\mathcal L$, containing $x,y$;
2. every line $L\in\mathcal L$ contains at least two distinct points;
3. $X$ is not a line;
4. for every line $L\in\mathcal L$ and point $x\in X\setminus L$ there exists a unique line $L_x\in\mathcal L$ such that $x\in L_x$ and $L\cap L_x=\varnothing$.

A bijection $F:X\to X$ of an affine plane $X$ is called

$\bullet$ a *collineation* of $X$ if for every line $L\in\mathcal L$ the sets $F[L]$ and $F^{-1}[L]$ are lines;

$\bullet$ a *dilation* if $F$ is a collineation such that for every line $L\in\mathcal L$ we have $F[L]=L$ or $F[L]\cap L=\varnothing$;

$\bullet$ a *translation* if $F$ is a dilation such that either $\forall x\in X\;F(x)=x$ or $\forall x\in X\;F(x)\ne x$.

Dilations and translations form normal subgroups $\Dil(X)$ and $\Trans(X)$ in the group of collineations $\Col(X)$ of an affine plane $X$.

> **Question.** Is the group of translations $\Trans(X)$ commutative for every affine plane $X$?

Comment: Theorem 6.13(3) in Casse's book *Projective Geometry: An Introduction* (Oxford 2006) looks like it might be relevant (it says that in a projective plane the set of “elations” with a given line $\ell$ as axis is an abelian group, and adds that this is known as the “translation group” with axis $\ell$). But I don't know if your definition of an “affine plane” is equivalent to his (a projective plane minus a line), so I don't know if this answers your question. But if you don't know it, you might wish to check the proof.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thank you for the comment. My affine planes are exactly projective planes minus a line, so the information concerning the group of elations with a fixed axis and a fixed center on this axis is exactly what I need. Problems with commutativity of the translation group appear when this group is small, namely, when all translations have the same fixed point at infinity (so are translations along the same line in the affine plane).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I looked at the proof of Theorem 6.13(3) and it does have an additional assumption that there exist two elations with different centers. Under this assumption the proof indeed works (and I knew this proof). But without extra assumptions, my question remains non-answered (at the moment).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had missed that.

Comment: Is it obvious that composing two translations gives a translation?

Comment: @YCor It is not obvious, but nonetheless true (and have a proof of this fact).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be an arbitrary countably-infinite group. I claim that there is an affine plane $X$ such that $\operatorname{Trans}(X)$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $G$.

By a back-and-forth argument one can show the existence of a function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to G$ which satisfy the following conditions:

1. For any $i_1,i_2\in\mathbb N$ such that $i_1\neq i_2$, the function $\mathbb N\to G$ given by $j\mapsto f(i_1,j)^{-1}f(i_2,j)$ is a bijection
2. For any $j_1,j_2\in\mathbb N$ such that $j_1\neq j_2$, the function $\mathbb N\to G$ given by $i\mapsto f(i,j_1)f(i,j_2)^{-1}$ is a bijection

Now, the points in our affine plane will be $\left\{\left(g, i\right): g\in G, i\in\mathbb N\right\} = G\times \mathbb N$, and the lines would be:

1. $\left\{\left(g, i_0\right):g\in G\right\}$ for a fixed $i_0\in\mathbb N$
2. $\left\{\left(g_0f(i,j_0),i\right):i\in\mathbb N\right\}$ for fixed $g_0\in G$, $j_0\in \mathbb N$

One can see that, given the conditions on $f$, this is an affine plane, and for any $h\in G$ the map $\left(g,i\right)\mapsto\left(hg,i\right)$ is a translation which is nontrivial when $h\neq 1$.

**Addition:**

If we also assume that $G$ is not commutative then for any choice of $f$ we actually have that $\operatorname{Trans}(X)$ is isomorphic to $G$.
It follows from the following lemma: for any affine plane $X$, if $u,v\in\operatorname{Trans}(X)$, $A\in X$, and $A, u(A), v(A)$ are not collinear then $u(v(A)) = v(u(A))$.

To use this lemma for our example, note that a translation of $X$ which does not come from $G$ must move $\left(1,1\right)\in X$ to some $\left(g,i_0\right)\in X$ with $i_0\neq 1$. Therefore the lemma implies that any $u\in\operatorname{Trans}(X)\setminus G$ must commute with any element of $G$. In particular, if $g,h\in G$ then both $u$ and $h\circ u$ must commute with $g$ which implies that $g,h$ are commuting.

To prove the lemma (assuming that $u,v$ are nontrivial), note that the line $\left[A,u(A)\right]$ is parallel both to the line $\left[v(A),v(u(A))\right]$ (because $v$ is a dilation) and also to the line $\left[v(A),u(v(A))\right]$ (because any line of the form $\left[P,u(P)\right]$ is conserved by $u$ (follows from being a dilation) and if two such lines would intersect then the intersection point would be fixed by $u$, contrary to $u$ being a nontrivial translation). Therefore it follows that $v(A), u(v(A)), v(u(A))$ are collinear. Similarly we have that $u(A), u(v(A)), v(u(A))$ are collinear. If $u(v(A))\neq v(u(A))$ then it follows that $u(A), v(A), u(v(A)), v(u(A))$ are collinear, and from above $A$ must also be on that line, so we get that $A, u(A), v(A)$ are collinear.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Very interesting! And unexpected. Truly speaking I hoped that $Trans(X)$ is commutative, according to a general belief. But could not find a correct proof of this generally accepted "fact".

Comment: Could you please write me your name (I want to include this your example to a book in Foundation of Geometry I am writing at the moment). Thank you!

Comment: @TarasBanakh I sent you an email now

Comment: I hope that your construction can be adjusted just a bit in order to obtain an affine plane $X$ whose group of translations $Trans(X)$ is isomorphic to any given countable group $G$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh It seems that if we assume that $G$ is not commutative then there cannot be any other translations than those from $G$, no matter which $f$ is chosen (I added a proof). So somewhat funnily the remaining case is where $G$ is commutative, which is the case you didn't ask about in the original question

Comment: You are right, of course, for non-commutative groups no other translations can appear, but it would be nice to obtain a general result: for every infinite group $G$, there exists an affine plane whose group of translation is isomorphic to $G$. So, one should "kill" somehow all other translations. This can be made by imposing suitable extra conditions in the inductive construction of your function $f$ (determining the lines in your affine plane).